# Error in SQL update query in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, string, jdbc

For the command given below, if the variable body_template contains " Abhinav's number", it shows the following error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's number

```
String sql_command = "Update email_template set body_template='"+body_template+"' WHERE    id="+idno; 
//body_template, idno are of type String 

stmt.executeUpdate(sql_command); //Here stmt is a variable of type statement.
```

Kindly suggest how should I redesign my query so as to handle such cases. Note: Input can't be changed. The problem is coming due to the inclusion of ' in the input.

Comment: what is the data type of `body_template` in database beacuse the problem is beacuse of `'s` in your value

Comment: Body_template is of type mediumtext

Comment: see my answer for the solution

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement` to pass the parameter. Apart from fixing your syntax error it will also prevent SQL injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Note: Input can't be changed. The problem is coming due to the inclusion of ' in the input.*

Best practice is to use [***`PreparedStatement`***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) for binding the input values with the query parameters. It manages to escape special characters if any in the input values.

**Example**:

```
// body_template, idno are of type String 
String sql_command = "Update email_template set body_template=? WHERE id=?";
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement( sql_command );
pst.setString( 1, body_template );
pst.setString( 2, idno );

int updateResult = pst.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: +1. Quick check - would you consider replacing the string in the code as changing input? I am not quite sure if my answer is within the constraints imposed.

Comment: To handle SQL syntax constraints, I don't prefer manual replacement of specific occurrences in the input strings. PST of the API is already serving that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql_command = "Update email_template set body_template=\""+body_template+"\" WHERE    id="+idno; 
//body_template, idno are of type String 

stmt.executeUpdate(sql_command); //Here stmt is a variable of type statement.
```

if body_template doesn't contain ", then this code would work. obviously if body_template does have it then you run into same problem as before. just make sure body_template only contains one type of quotes